# Retrieving Nearby Tweets, Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-7.1

I was trying to find if I could be able to get tweets around my current geo location using Twitter API or any other API using Windows Phone 7.1 and C#? For example all the Tweets with radios range 2 miles of my current location with a time stamp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do anything if you put your mind to it.

Comment: @Brandon yeah sure, but my question aims to know if I would be able to retrieve user Lat and Long. I read somewhere that Twitter doesn't share users GeoLocations, so I was trying to make sure I can implement the App by retrieving tweets nearby me.